# How to use fixed position in fluid layout

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have a WP blog with fluid layout, the main content is in a centered div, about 1000px wide.

Now I want to put an ad banner area on each side, and I want to use fixed on the position so that these ad:s stay when user scrolls down the blog.

I have seen blogs with similar ad's but they don't have the fluid layout but instead can use the position: fixed and width:Ypx left:-Ypx which make their ad fixed nicely on the left side always.

It seems that this is not possible though with a fluid layout?

This is the effect I am trying to mimic, see how both sides don't scroll down...

http://radarmagazine.se WRONG SITE

--- update ---------

I put the wrong sample site.. this is the one with fixed positions:

THIS IS THE SAMPLE SITE:
http://freshnet.com

Comment: I believe you mean "tower" ads, not "banner" ads. Banner ads are landscape, tower ads are portrait.

Comment: There are no fixed elements on the example website you gave other then the nav bar.

Comment: If you add some code, and a JSFiddle, it will be easier for others to understand the problem and to provide help.

Comment: The website above is using a background position fixed to do it since it is just a background image not a tower.

Comment: I put the wrong sample site, it's updated now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible without JS. Here's my approach.

Basically, you'd want to setup your containing div, then clone it and set it within a `div` dedicated to `position: fixed;` that way the cloned container within the fixed `div`  will share the same styles as your actual containing div and scale accordingly.

```
<div class="ads"> <!-- Dedicated position: fixed; -->
    <div class="wrap"> <!-- Cloned container for positioning of Ads -->
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x750&text=Ad1" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x750&text=Ad2" /> 
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap"> <!-- Main container with a z-index of 1 -->
    <img class="main" src="http://placehold.it/960x300" />
</div>
```

Once that's in place, you can position your "ads" accordingly within the fixed div, and position them outside of the responsive / fixed container so they adhere to it - giving the illusion that they're adhering to your actual wrapper. And after your `max-width` is reached the fixed ads will be pushed out of the viewport.

http://jsfiddle.net/m0v3vqcp/ - Fiddle

[Full Screen](http://jsfiddle.net/m0v3vqcp/embedded/result/) /
[With Their Ads](http://jsfiddle.net/nk4rnb3w/)

Comment: Kept this as unobtrusive and tame as possible - so you can remove the ads wrapper without any issues or dependencies on negative margins, etc.

Comment: Thanks, awesome solution. One question - putting a max-width on the whole thing removes some of the original design (the header image used to span the entire area margin to margin regardless it's size). Any nifty way to keep that (either continuing outside the ad's, or only showing when there are no ads..

Comment: Are you speaking to trying to have the ads scale as well, including the header? Looks like I forgot `height: auto;` on `.main` which is the header image ad. http://jsfiddle.net/6xqbq0nt/

Answer (score 0):

It's possible using some JavaScript, fetching the width of the content on the `window.resize` event and then updating your Ads position on the x-axis based on that value. I made a JSFiddle to illustrate how this could be achieved.

http://jsfiddle.net/r86r6j1f/

Answer (score 0):

You can use padding on the `body` to make room for the banners, a quick example:

http://jsfiddle.net/dpcd3c1b/

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you need Javascript for it. You should be able to do it with a couple of relative positioned floats and positioned fixed.

http://jsfiddle.net/9ov32nkd/1/

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
    min-width: 960px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#inner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 960px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -480px;
}

.content {
    width: 720px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #CCC;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: left;
}

.banner {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

.banner1 {
    float: left;
}

.banner1 .inner,
.banner2 .inner {
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

.banner2 {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Evan's solution is better than the one I provided.